# Странное поведение метода для получения данных с коллекции Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-database

Почему метод для получения данных с коллекции ведет себя неправильно?

```
public List<Note> loadNotes(){
    database.collection(NoteCollection.COLLECTION_NAME)
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener(queryDocumentSnapshots -> {
                notes.addAll(queryDocumentSnapshots.toObjects(Note.class));
                Log.d("loadingNote", String.valueOf(notes.size()));
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                Log.d("loadingNote", e.toString());
            });
    Log.d("loadingNote", String.valueOf(notes.size()));
    return notes;
}
```

Дело в том, что addOnSuccessListener отрабатывает правильно. То есть в лист добавляется два элемента. Но перед return проверяю лист и оказывается, что в нем вообще нету элементов. Хотя они же добавились в addOnSuccessListener. Почему так происходит и как решить эту проблему?

Вот логи:

```
2019-02-26 07:42:04.194 12548-12548/com.rafalsky.firebaselesson1 D/loadingNote: 0
2019-02-26 07:42:06.452 12548-12548/com.rafalsky.firebaselesson1 D/loadingNote: 2
```

Заранее благодарен за помощь.

Comment: addOnSuccessListener() Выполняется в асинхронном потоке.
А ваш return notes выполняется последовательно. То есть он выполнится раньше, чем произойдет загрузка данных. Это можно решить через интерфейсы и другими способами. Зависит от вашей архитектуры

Comment: Подскажите, как это реализовать с помощью интерфейсов?

Comment: Если подождете до вечера(для меня это через 4-5 часа). Я выложу ответ как вы можете сделать в вашем случае, как можно это реализовать на MVP(Mosby) или MVVM. Только нужно одно уточнение, это активити или фрагмент? А так же где выходите вызывать этот код, в другом фрагменте или активности?

Comment: Этот метод лежит во ViewModel. Во фрагменте с RecycleView я получаю viewModel, вызываю этот метод для получения данных из коллекции и передаю полученый лист в адаптер.

Comment: @Виталий Робиновкий Вот ссылка на проект https://github.com/AndreyRafalsky13/NoteManager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я посмотрел ваш проект. И есть конечно несколько идей как улучшить:

1. Храните Fragment, ViewModel, ViewModelFactory(если используете свой) в одном пакете. Так читать код намного проще. Так же адаптер в под пакете "adapter";
2. Используйте асинхронные вызовы для обращение к БД.

Я приведу пример на Kotlin(надеюсь вы сможете разобраться и перевести на Java):

Fragment

```
   override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        viewModel.notes.observe(this, Observer<ArrayList<Note>> {
            it?.let(::initAdapter)
        })
    }


    private fun initAdapter(list: ArrayList<Note>) {
        recyclerView.run {
            adapter = RegistrationAdapter(this@RegistrationFragment)
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
            (adapter as RegistrationAdapter).setData(list)
        }
    }
```

ViewModel

```
var notes = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Note>>()

    fun load() {
        database.collection(NoteCollection.COLLECTION_NAME).get().addOnSuccessListener({ queryDocumentSnapshots ->
            notes.value = queryDocumentSnapshots.toObjects(Note::class.java)
            Log.d("loadingNote", String.valueOf(notes.size()))
        }).addOnFailureListener({ e -> Log.d("loadingNote", e.toString()) })
    }
```

Я использую `LiveData` для отслеживания списка. Советую почитать [StartAndroid LiveData](https://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/architecture-components/27-course/architecture-components/525-urok-2-livedata.html)

Comment: спасибо большое за помощь

Comment: @АндрейРафальский разобрались?

Comment: да, спасибо огромное :)